# How to update customer_entity table from observer in magento 2.1.9?

Tags: magento-2.1.9

I want to update the "`customer_entity`" table on `adminhtml_customer_save_after` event and trying to do so with the help of an observer.
How can i do that?

Comment: what changes you want?

Comment: I am using customer activation, if the customer is activated i want the 'isactive' field to be updated.'

Comment: how  we we know that customer is active ?

Comment: Thats what I am trying to do, I have placed a check box on admin html customer information tab. If the user checks that and save the customer then "customer_entity table" should get updated.

Answer (score 0):

***try this observer for save customer data:***

```
<?php
namespace {VendorName}\{Vendorname}\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerMetadataInterface;
/**
 * @category   Devamitbera
 * @package    Devamitbera_Common
 * @author     Amit Bera <dev.amitbera@gmail.com>
 * @website    http://www.amitbera.com
* @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */
class {ClassName}  implements ObserverInterface
{

    protected $_customerRepository;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface = $_customerRepository;

    ) {
        $this->_customerRepository = $_customerRepository;
    }
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {

        $customerId = $this->getCurrentCustomerId($observer->getRequest());
        $customer = $observer->getCustomer();

        if ($customer->getId() && 
            (boolean)$observer->getRequest()->getParam('{Your_Custom_Field}', false)) {
            $customer->setCustomAttribute('is_active', true);
            $this->_customerRepository->save($customer);
        }

     }

}
```

Comment: I am already using the "CustomerRepositoryInterface"  tried to do so with that object also but its not working, 'is_active'  is not a custom attribute of customer_entity table.

Comment: Any other way how can i directly make database changes from observer?